# Problema con el Constructor (C++ Error C2512, no appropriate default constructor available)

Tags: c++

Necesito que mi constructor inicie cada elemento de mi arreglo en `0.0`, pero con mi código me dice que:

```
Error C2512 'Vendedor': no appropriate default constructor available".
```

Anexo el código:

```
#pragma once 
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
class Vendedor
{
 public: 
   Vendedor(float Ventas[12]);
   void asignaventas(float);
   void imprimeventas();
 private: 
   float Ventas[12];
   float VentasTotal; 
   float CalVtasTotal(float);  
   float Ventastotal =0; }
```

---

```
#include "Vendedor.h"
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

Vendedor::Vendedor(float Ventas[12]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        this->Ventas[i] = 0.0f;
    }
}

void Vendedor::asignaventas(float Ventas) {
    float x = 0;
    cout << "Introdusca la cantidad de ventas realizadas en los 12 meses: "<<endl; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        cin >> x; 
        this->Ventas[i] = x;
    } 
} 

void Vendedor::imprimeventas() {
    cout << " Las ventas ascienden a: " << CalVtasTotal(Ventas[12]) << endl;;
}

float Vendedor::CalVtasTotal(float Ventas) {  
    float total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) { 
    total = total + this->Ventas[i];
    }  
    this->VentasTotal = total;
    return VentasTotal;
}
```

---

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "Vendedor.h"
using namespace std; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    Vendedor ob; //aquí marca el error
    ob.asignaventas(12); 
    ob.imprimeventas();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Llevo mucho tiempo sin trabajar con C++, pero si no me equivoco el problema es cómo se define y se llama el constructor: ahora mismo `Vendedor` sólo tiene un constructor, que toma como parámetro de entrada un array de `float` con tamaño 12:

```
Vendedor::Vendedor(float Ventas[12])
```

Pero cuando se declara el objeto se hace de esta manera:

```
Vendedor ob;
```

Que lo que intenta es llamar a un constructor sin parámetros, que no está definido en el código (por eso marca error en esa línea).

La solución sería definir un nuevo constructor (puede haber más de uno) que no tenga parámetros y que utilice un array por defecto dentro:

```
Vendedor::Vendedor()
```

Alternativamente, hacer algo como esto: `Vendedor ob = new Vendedor(arr);`, habiendo definido arr como un array de float de tamaño 12.

Comment: no utilice lo que me sugeriste pero me hiciste darme cuenta de que estaba olvidando lo de los parámetros, muchas gracias, ya lo solucione.

Answer (score 2):

Tal y como ya ha respondido [Alvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4527/2742) uno de los problemas que tienes es haber creado un constructor que recibe un parámetro, lo cuál evita que se pueda construir un `Vendedor` sin facilitar parámetro, eso es totalmente cierto, así que yo me voy a centrar en responder tu cuestión sobre que el "*constructor inicie cada elemento de mi arreglo en 0.0*".

Tal y como ya ha sido mencionado, no debes crear constructor, puedes inicializar a 0 todos los miembros en el lugar de creación tal y cómo ya haces con `Ventas::VentasTotal`:

```
class Vendedor
{
public: 
    // Sin constructor
    void asignaventas(float);
    void imprimeventas();
private: 
    float Ventas[12] = {}; // Inicializa a 0 los 12 elementos
    float VentasTotal = .0f; 
    float CalVtasTotal(float);
    float Ventastotal = .0f;
};
```

Dado que `Ventas[12]` es un agregado puede beneficiarse de la [inicialización de agregados](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), que como puede verse en el enlace facilitado:

> Si el número de cláusulas inicializador es menor que el número de miembros **o la lista de inicialización está completamente vacía**, los miembros restantes se inicializalizarán con sus inicializadores por defecto, si han sido proveídos en la definición de la clase, o en caso contrario (desde C++14) por listas vacías, que **realizan una inicialización-valor**.

(He modificado el texto pues la traducción automática era *extraña*, el resaltado en negrita es mío)

En el caso de `float` la [inicialización-valor](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) realiza una [inicialización a cero](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization):

> 1. Para cada variable llamada con duración de almacenamiento estático o local de subprocesos, antes de cualquier otra inicialización.
> 2. **Como parte de la secuencia de inicialización-valor de tipos que no sean clases y para los miembros sin constructor de clases inicializadas por valor**.
> 3. Cuando una matriz de caracteres es inicializada con una cadena literal que es demasiado corto, el resto de la matriz es cero inicializa.

(He modificado el texto pues la traducción automática era *extraña*, el resaltado en negrita es mío)

Con los cambios sugeridos se puede usar `Vendedor` de la siguiente manera:

```
int main()
{
    Vendedor v; // v.Ventas inicializado a 0, igual que el resto de miembros
    v.imprimeventas(); // Todo debe ser 0
    return 0;
}
```

Puede verse que no hemos pasado parámetros al constructor pues se usa el constructor por defecto (que no recibe parámetros) que el propio compilador ha generado por nosotros.

Como alternativas a `float Ventas[12] = {};` tenemos:

```
float Ventas[12]{};
float Ventas[12] = { .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f };
float Ventas[12]{ .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f, .0f };
```

Consiguiendo todas ellas el mismo efecto de poner a 0 todos los valores del arreglo.

Puedes ver <kbd>[aquí](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OBHIy7xOw7oywndl)</kbd> un ejemplo de uso.

#### PD:

Si estamos inicializando valores `float` yo prefiero usar literales `float`; un literal `0` es de tipo `int`, mientras que un literal `0.0` es de tipo `double`.